# Why doesn't typedefs work when used as a generic as well in dart

Tags: dart

I've been playing around with generics and typedefs to see how far I can take typing in dart, and I found that I have trouble assigning an instance member that has a type alias to a function. This code here:

```dart
abstract class RouteHandler<HandlerArgs> {
  HandlerArgs get handler;
}

class LoginRouteHandler<LoginRouteArgs> extends RouteHandler {
  LoginRouteArgs navigate = ({
    required String username,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    print('we doing joing');
    return;
  };

  @override
  get handler => navigate;
}

typedef LoginRouteArgs = Future<void> Function({
  required String password,
  required String username,
});

class RouteNavigator {
  HandlerArgs getHandler<HandlerArgs>({required String routeName}) {
    var stuff = <String, RouteHandler<dynamic> Function()>{
      "Login": LoginRouteHandler.new
    };

    var loginThing = stuff[routeName];
    return loginThing!().handler;
  }
}

void main() {
  var routeNavigator = RouteNavigator();
  var navigateToLogin = routeNavigator.getHandler<LoginRouteArgs>(routeName: 'Login');
  navigateToLogin(
    username: 'josh',
    password: 'joshiewashie',
  );
}
```

Returns this error on line 6:

```
A value of type 'Future<Null> Function({required String password, required String username})' 
can't be assigned to a variable of type 'LoginRouteArgs'.
```

I tried playing around with it, by changing the return types to be the same and "String", but the error persists. What could possibly cause this, and is there a fix?

If I remove the `LoginRouteArgs` generic on line 5 it works just fine.

Comment: Your problem is that `LoginRouteHandler` is a generic class with a type parameter named `LoginRouteArgs`.  That type parameter has no relationship to the `LoginRouteArgs` `typedef` (which gets shadowed). Why is `LoginRouteHandler` generic at all?

Comment: @jamesdlin, I put the generic argument in the wrong place 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I put the generic in the wrong place, the `LoginRouteHandler` should be defined like this:

```dart
class LoginRouteHandler extends RouteHandler<LoginRouteArgs> {}
```

Comment: Correct. The original code introduced a new type variable named `LoginRouteArgs` which shadowed the `typedef`. The function type was not assignable to that (completely unconstrained) type varaible.